# How to avoid using "on" twice in the same sentence

Tags: writing

How to avoid using "on" twice in the same sentence?

For example "my part concentrate on the impact on the industrial and transportation sectors."

Comment: The question does not seem to make sense because it does not supply the reason why one would think that this sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

> "my part **is centered around** the impact on the industrial and transportation sectors."

Or avoiding present perfect:

> "my part **centers around** the impact on the industrial and transportation sectors."

You could also change the other on:

> "my part concentrate**s** on the **repercussions for** the industrial and transportation sectors."

Just avoid using a word [(try a thesaurus for that)](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/focus?s=t) which needs **on** as a preposition.